# python - automation of for loop to cover arbitrary number of keys in dict

Tags: python

So I need to look at the some function `f`, which depends on a variety of parameters, summarised in a `dict` that I called `data`.

Some paramters in `data` are fixed, like `data['focus']`, while others I would like to change.

I write in `temp`, another `dict`, the parameters that I want to change. My function `Trial` then takes all combinations of the varying parameters and calculates `f` each time, saving its result and the parameters into a `dict` of `dicts` `calcdata`, where each computation is saved in `calcdata[counter]`.

I have provided a minimal working example below.
This works and I can already use it (I have simplified the function `f` though). 
As you can see, though, I am limited to sets of 3 parameters.

---

Is there a way I can make it such that this can accept an arbitrary number of `keys` in `temp`? 
 Basically I would like some sort of automation such that I don't have to write `value0` and `keys[0]`. 
 So ideally it would read off how many `keys` there are, and performs as many `for` loops required to cover them all.

```
import numpy as np

def f(data, t):
    x = data['focus']*data['integration']*data['upper']
    return t*x

def Trial(t, temp, data):

    calcdata = {}
    counter = 0

    keys = temp.keys()

    for value0 in temp[keys[0]]:
        for value1 in temp[keys[1]]:
            for value2 in temp[keys[2]]:
                data[keys[0]] = value0
                data[keys[1]] = value1
                data[keys[2]] = value2
                x_axis, y_axis = np.vstack((t,np.vectorize(f)(data,t)))
                calcdata[counter] = {}
                calcdata[counter]['xaxis'] = x_axis
                calcdata[counter]['yaxis'] = y_axis            
                calcdata[counter][keys[0]] = value0  
                calcdata[counter][keys[1]] = value1
                calcdata[counter][keys[2]] = value2
                counter+=1

    return calcdata

data['focus'] = 100
t = np.linspace(1,10,10)
temp = {'integration': [1,2], 'upper':  [3,4], 'other':  [5,6]}

calcdata = Trial(t, temp, data)
```

Comment: It appears that `temp` is a dict whose values are lists and you want all combinations of each of those list items. So, `{'foo':[1,2], 'bar':[3,4]}` would give 4 results. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes that it exactly it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general idea you can use:

```
from itertools import product

temp = {'integration': [1, 2], 'upper': [3, 4], 'other': [5, 6]}
keys = list(temp.keys())
data = {}
for values in product(*temp.values()):
    data.update(zip(keys, values))
    print(data)
```

(because of the separate accesses to keys and values, this is not thread safe on `temp`)

Comment: I don't think that `dict` guarantees that keys will list in the same order of values. And if some `temp` value lists have different sizes, the zip won't work either.

Comment: @tdelaney [it does guarantee that](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), and the zip works fine in that case since the length of my `values` variable doesn't depend on the length of those values lists.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` gives you the combinations that you want. The problem is that you need to rebuild dictionaries from its result. In this example, I expanded `temp` into `(key, value)` tuples which can be used to update the `data` dictionary. I copy `data` so that I don't have to worry about stale data on each loop.

I made this a runnable python 2 script with extra prints to show the intermediate steps.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def f(data, t):
    x = data['focus']*data['integration']*data['upper']
    return t*x

def Trial(t, temp, data):

    calcdata = {}

    # make list of (key:value) pairs for each value list
    temp_vector = [[(key, value) for value in valuelist]
        for key,valuelist in temp.iteritems()]
    print "temp_vector"
    for item in temp_vector:
        print item
    print "-------------------------------"

    # run for all combinations
    for counter, subs in enumerate(itertools.product(*temp_vector)):
        mydata = data.copy()
        mydata.update(subs)
        print "dict for calcuation:", mydata
        x_axis, y_axis = np.vstack((t,np.vectorize(f)(mydata,t)))
        mydata['xaxis'] = x_axis
        mydata['yaxis'] = y_axis
        calcdata[counter] = mydata 

    print "--------------------------------"
    return calcdata

#data['focus'] = 100
data = {'focus':100}
t = np.linspace(1,10,10)
temp = {'integration': [1,2], 'upper':  [3,4], 'other':  [5,6]}

calcdata = Trial(t, temp, data)

for item in sorted(calcdata.items()):
    print(item)
```